# Prove that $\frac{2d}{\exp(-2\log(2d))} \le \frac{1}{2d}$

Tags: inequality, logarithms, fractions

For $d > 0$ and $\log x = \log_ex$ (second one is shortened version of log)

$$\frac{2d}{\exp(-2\log(2d))} \le \frac{1}{2d}$$

So far my steps are, from logarithmic property:
$$\exp(-2\log(2d)) = \exp(\log(2d)^{-2}) = (2d)^{-2} = \frac{1}{4d^2} $$

And therefore:
$$\frac{2d}{\exp(-2\log(2d))} = \frac{2d}{\frac{1}{4d^2}} = 8d^3$$
Which can't be less or equal than $\frac{1}{2d}$.
What am I supposing wrong?

Comment: I think there should be positive sign the exponential on the LHS.

Comment: You are not doing anything wrong. The inequality is valid only for $d \le 1/2$ which is what you would get too if you solve $8d^3 \le \dfrac{1}{2d}$.

Comment: @AryamanMaithani You are right, I just realised I oversaw the obvious mistake I couldn't see for 3 days, and I thought I was crazy. I messed up a sign in a fraction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $e(\cdot)>0$ and $d>0$, you can rewrite

$$
e^{-2 \log 2d}\geq 4d^2 \implies \frac{1}{4d^2} \geq 4d^2 \implies (4d^2-1)(4d^2+1) \leq 0
$$
In $\mathbb{R}$ this has solution when $(2d-1)(2d+1) \leq 0$, which has a solution when $-\frac{1}{2} \leq d \leq \frac{1}{2}$, and now combine it together with the condition on $d$ that you have